# Using shell.js with cat command in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cat

I need to use shelljs in Node.js. I write this two lines for getting standart output and writing it into something.xml file by using cat command. But with this style, the stdout will shown in the terminal. I don't want to it. How can I fix it ? Do I need to use something different ? I don't want to anything in the terminal about stdout, I need "stdout" only in a file.

```
var sh = require('shelljs');    
var xyz = sh.cat('./something.xml').stdout;
```